# Resolution of WaitForSingleObject with timeSetEvent & SetWaitableTimer

Tags: winapi, waitforsingleobject

I am using a Win32 multimedia timer to put a delay between the dispatch of large numbers of UDP packets, but i am finding that the resulting delay is substantially longer than it should be. Delays of ~40ms are sometimes nearer 1000ms, even when using Windows Miltimedia timers and upping the timer resolution. Below is a simplifed version of the code i used:

```
if( timeGetDevCaps(&tc,sizeof(TIMECAPS)) == TIMERR_NOERROR) 
    {
    timeRes = min( max(tc.wPeriodMin,1), tc.wPeriodMax);
    timeBeginPeriod(timeRes);
    printf("Timer Res: %u\n", timeRes);
    }
/* ... */
while( ptrHead )
    {
    NALU_t *ptrLink = ptrHead;
    unsigned long tsNALU = ptrLink->timestamp - tsFirst;
    printf("Timestamp: %umsec\n", ptrLink->timestamp / 90 );
    int idxPort;
    for(idxPort=0;idxPort<12;idxPort++)
        {
        ip4Addr.sin_port = htons( 60000 + idxPort );
        struct sockaddr *saAddr = (struct sockaddr*)&ip4Addr;
        sendto(fdSocket,(char*)ptrLink->ptrData,ptrLink->lenData,
           0,saAddr,lenAddr);
        }
    if( 1 )
        {
        unsigned long millis = (tsNALU - tsPrev) / 90;
        valTime.QuadPart  = 10000;
        valTime.QuadPart *= millis;
        valTime.QuadPart *= -1;
        if(SetWaitableTimer(hdlTimer,&valTime,0,NULL,NULL,TIME_ONESHOT))
            WaitForSingleObject(hdlTimer,INFINITE);
        }
    tsPrev = tsNALU;
    ptrHead = ptrLink->next;
    free( ptrLink );
    }
```

I *suspect* the problem is that Windows7 no longer guarantees the resolution of timers when signalled by events as opposed to call-backs, but i am loathed to use the latter. Anyone know why even supposedly high-resolution timers in single-threaded test cases are so wildly inaccurate?

Comment: It's never guaranteed the resolution of the timers. They're still dependant on anythign else the process/system is doing. When not loaded they should be close enough though.

Comment: I know it is abuse of term to put 'guarantee' and 'Windows' in the same sentence, but the accuracy of WinMM shouldn't be anywhere this *bad*.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If timing is critical it's best to run in a busy loop (you can give up a timeslice every iteration using Sleep(0) if you want), using the QueryPerformanceCounter() API to measure elapsed time.

Comment: I had intended to avoid busy loops, but the MSDN page for the function had a remark about using SetThreadAffinityMask(), which put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

From subsequent experiments, my best guess is that Windows moving threads between CPU cores (possibly for load-balancing reasons - this is on a Quad-core i7) is disruptive to timing functions. I used `SetThreadAffinityMask()` to lock my timing-critical thread to one CPU (and my non-timing threads to all other cores), and that has sorted out the problems.